# Graphics CopyFromScreen off when font/icon scaling is enabled

Tags: c#, graphics, fonts, scaling

Need some help with C# Windows Forms program. This is on .NET 4.0.

I use the following (snippet of) code to capture a composited image from my window:

```
var location = PointToScreen(picVisualizer.Location);
...
g.CopyFromScreen(location, new Point(0, 0), picVisualizer.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

picVisualizer is a PictureBox control in my window.
This works perfectly as intended, as long as the user keeps Windows font/icon scaling at 100%. If they change, the image captured is the right size but is offset, capturing part of the window, the desktop, etc.

I've tried a variety of solutions but they always give me the same location value, so the end result is the same. I've also tried AutoScaleMode to None, Font, Dpi and Inherit, and all four gave me the same result.

Is there a way to tweak that code so it'll capture the correct part of the screen even when display scaling is not at 100%?

Thanks.

Comment: Does [`picVisualizer.DrawToBitmap()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) work?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes that worked beautifully, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer suggested by Blorgbeard works beautifully.

```
picVisualizer.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, picVisualizer.ClientRectangle);
```

Thanks.